# Como fazer no WizzardPager, construir uma Fragment de acordo com a escolha do usuário?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-fragment

Estou usando o WizzardPager baseado nesse [aqui](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager). Porém o que quero é basicamente o usuário escolhe o sexo da pessoa, e passa pra outra tela do WizzardPager onde nesta, irá escolher a etnia dela, de acordo com a escolha do sexo. Por exemplo: se a escolha de sexo foi "Masculino", as opções de etnia será "negro", "pardo", "caucasiano"; caso escolheu sexo "Feminino", as opções de etnia será "negra", "parda", "caucasiana".

Porém a tela de sexo aparece normalmente, e seleciona um sexo, mas não passa pra tela correspondente a escolha do sexo, não aparece. Existe uma alternativa, pois estou usando o BranchPage do [WizzardPager](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá uma olhada no projeto exemplo da WizardPager: https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager/tree/master/sample.

Nela tem uma classe que chama `SandwichWizardModel`, que contem toda a árvore de opções do Wizard.

Fiz umas modificações e consegui reproduzir seu caso:

```
// ...

@Override
protected PageList onNewRootPageList() {
    return new PageList(new BranchPage(this, "Sexo")
            .addBranch("Masculino",
                    new SingleFixedChoicePage(this, "Etnia")
                            .setChoices("Negro", "Pardo", "Caucasiano")
                            .setRequired(true))
            .addBranch("Feminino",
                    new SingleFixedChoicePage(this, "Etnia")
                            .setChoices("Negra", "Parda", "Caucasiana")
                            .setRequired(true))
    );
}

// ...
```

Só para saber, as opções para sexo feminino era assim mesmo? Porque na sua pergunta estavam iguais ao do sexo masculino.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, ajudou o meu problema